# Is there a more efficent way of "expanding" a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

An algorithm requires me to add an additional variable into a square matrix, this results in adding a row and column to the matrix. I can use the np.insert method as shown below, but was wondering if there was a better way to do this to an already existing allocated array?

I was trying to play around with a masked write, but have not been successful:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = np.array([[1,3,4,5],
               [11,13,14,15],
               [16,18,19,20],
               [21,23,24,25]
              ])

row_1 = np.array([6,8,9,10])
col_1 = np.array([2,7,12,17,22])

m2 = np.insert(m1, 1, row_1, axis=0)
m2 = np.insert(m2, 1, col_1, axis=1)
print(f'{m2=}')

# create a mask to copy data from m1
m1_mask = np.ones(tuple(np.array(m1.shape) + 1), dtype=int)
expanded_m1 = np.zeros(tuple(np.array(m1.shape) + 1))
m1_mask[:,1] = 0
m1_mask[1, :] = 0
print(m1_mask)
# only write the indices where there are 1's from the original m1 data
expanded_m1[m1_mask] = m1
print(expanded_m1)
```

Comment: Define "better". When you say _" already existing allocated array"_, do you mean you've already created `m2` of the correct size, and you want to assign `m1` to the correct indices?

Comment: Better in terms of memory and computational efficiency. I assumed there is a better way than calling two insert functions. Yes, I know what size I want the array to be, so I can create a blank array m2, I was hoping to be able to write m1's contents into m2, but cannot find a way to do so.

Comment: Are you doing this often? Should you maybe use a different data structure?

Comment: You hardcoded index `1`, even into the variable names (`row_1` and `col_1`). Does that mean you only need to insert at that index, not at other indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `expanded_m1[m1_mask] = m1` fails because the LHS refers to `(5, 5, 5)` array.

```
>>> expanded_m1[m1_mask].shape
(5, 5, 5)
```

It becomes a mask if you make `m1_mask` a *boolean* array with `dtype=bool` at its definition. After setting `m1_mask[:, 1] = 0` and `m1_mask[1, :] = 0`, we have `m1_mask` as:

```
[[ True False  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True False  True  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True]]
```

Then, `expanded_m1[m1_mask]` returns a *vector* of elements, because it has no way to know that the result is actually a non-ragged array.

```
>>> expanded_m1[m1_mask].shape
(16,)

>>> m1_mask.sum()
16
```

You can set these elements if you also flatten `m1`:

```
>>> expanded_m1[m1_mask] = m1.flatten()
>>> print(expanded_m1)
[[ 1.  0.  3.  4.  5.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [11.  0. 13. 14. 15.]
 [16.  0. 18. 19. 20.]
 [21.  0. 23. 24. 25.]]
```

Then, you can set your new row and column. Some shenanigans are required because `row` has only four elements, but that is easy to handle:

```
row_mask = m1_mask[0]
expanded_m1[1, row_mask] = row_1
expanded_m1[:, 1] = col_1
```

However, this isn't significantly faster. Consider the plot below that shows performance comparisons for the `np.insert` approach vs. the masking approach vs. setting each "piece" of the new array explicitly, as [Kelly shows in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75805072/843953). It's ~2x quicker to just set everything manually instead of creating a mask.

```
def insert(arr, row_1, col_1):
    return np.insert(np.insert(arr, 1, row_1, axis=0), 1, col_1, axis=1)

def alloc_then_assign(arr, row_1, col_1):
    m1_mask = np.ones(np.array(arr.shape) + 1, dtype=bool)
    expanded_m1 = np.zeros_like(m1_mask, dtype=arr.dtype)
    m1_mask[:,1] = 0
    m1_mask[1, :] = 0
    expanded_m1[m1_mask] = arr.flatten()
    row_mask = m1_mask[0]
    expanded_m1[1, row_mask] = row_1
    expanded_m1[:, 1] = col_1
    return expanded_m1
```

[image]

Comment: @Kelly Sure. I was in the process of adding the same thing to my answer, but you beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks. I have one more that's simpler and faster, but assumes insertion is always at index 1. Probably no good :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another:

```
def piecewise(m1, row_1, col_1):
    m3 = np.empty(np.array(m1.shape) + 1, dtype=m1.dtype)
    m3[0, 0] = m1[0, 0]
    m3[0, 2:] = m1[0, 1:]
    m3[2:, 0] = m1[1:, 0]
    m3[2:, 2:] = m1[1:, 1:]
    m3[1, 0] = row_1[0]
    m3[1, 2:] = row_1[1:]
    m3[:, 1] = col_1
    return m3
```